I don't understand @Component and @WebFilter
I'm working on a Spring Boot project that is functioning normally.
I want to register a filter, but I find that I need to use both @Component and @WebFilter for the filter to intercept requests.
However, I noticed that some blogs about Spring Boot only use @WebFilter, and the filter still gets registered, which confuses me.
@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", filterName = "xssFilter")
public class XssFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }



    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        Filter.super.destroy();
    }
}

Then I created a regular SSM project without Spring Boot and found that whether or not I include @Component, the filter registered with @WebFilter still works the same way.
I also tried rewriting a Spring Boot project but did not use the embedded Tomcat; instead, I used an external Tomcat server.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

At this point, when I include both @Component and @WebFilter, I get an error:
"Failed to register 'filter xssFilter' on the servlet context. Possibly already registered?"
When I remove @Component and only use @WebFilter, the program runs normally, and the requests are intercepted by the filter.
I've read many posts online but still can't understand this issue.

Component is for makring a class for DI managed by spring framework. Seems one is registering it by default implicitly and when you are mixing them they are incompatible.

When using @Component + @WebFilter, you're actually registering the filter twice with Embedded Tomcat:

@Component registers it through Spring's component scanning
@WebFilter registers it through servlet container's scanning

This is why using both annotations works, but it's not the recommended approach
but in Traditional Spring MVC (External Tomcat):

@WebFilter is a standard Jakarta EE annotation that's processed by the servlet container (Tomcat)
@Component is a Spring framework annotation

When using external Tomcat, the servlet container handles @WebFilter registration directly
This is why you get the "already registered" error when using both annotations
=> Working with Just @WebFilter require using @ServletComponentScan in the Spring Boot application, This annotation enables scanning for servlet components including @WebFilter
